# Why using ng-value in place of value is causing infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

In the following code, if I use ng-value in place value, it causes Infinite $digest Loop, how ?

```
<select ng-model="opt">
  <option ng-repeat="option in data"
    value="{{option}}" >{{option.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Data here is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-value` is designed for radio buttons. Since your'e using `<select>`, **best to use `ng-options`.**

#### **For example,**

Online demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/3C68UlMKW574cT0BV1pE?p=preview

**html**

```
<select ng-model="opt" ng-options="item.name for item in data"></select>
<pre>selected item : {{opt}}</pre>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: 'one',
    id: 30
  }, {
    name: 'two',
    id: 27
  }, {
    name: 'three',
    id: 50
  }];

  $scope.opt = $scope.data[0];
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/3C68UlMKW574cT0BV1pE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Jossef, Can you explain why Infinite $digest Loop happens.